# How to specify the ListCollectionView that Telerik PropertyGrid uses?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm using PropertyGrid to see, edit, add and remove values for properties of an external class I cannot modify. The class contains a lot of `List<string>`, `List<int>`, `List<Guid>` properties, so that means I cannot add values to these lists using the PropertyGrid because it doesn't know how to instantiate them.

So my initial idea was to wrap each type using a class that looks like this:

```
public class ValueOf<T>
{
   public T Value { get; set; }

   public ValueOf()
   {
       Value = default(T);
   }

   public ValueOf(T valueContent)
   {
       Value = valueContent;
   }
}
```

... but that means I'll have to use a View Model for this class I cannot modify and write each property like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ValueOf<string>> Names{ get; set; }
```

So I searched a little more and I found this link: http://www.michaelruck.de/2012_07_01_archive.html

It talks about writing a custom ListCollectionView in order for the adding to work in a DataGrid, but it seems like something that would work for the PropertyGrid too. It looks something likes this:

```
public class TypedListCollectionView<T> : ListCollectionView, IEditableCollectionView
{
    private Func<T> factory;

    public TypedListCollectionView(IList collection, Func<T> factory)
        : base(collection)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    bool IEditableCollectionView.CanAddNew
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CanAddNewItem;
        }
    }

    object IEditableCollectionView.AddNew()
    {
        T obj = this.factory();
        return this.AddNewItem(obj);
    }
}
```

My question is how can I specify which ListCollectionView should the PropertyGrid use? I'm new to WPF and it seems like I'm missing something.